# Treat fullscreen as desktop spaces in the matter of navigation

Tags: keyboard, macos, spaces, fullscreen

As the title says, I'd like to treat an app fullscreen as a desktop in the matter of navigation in Yosemite 10.10.

I’am working with 2 monitors + 3 apps in fullscreen mode and do a lot with the keyboard. My problem is that I often want to change the focus between the monitors or between two fullscreen apps of one monitor. My question is, is there a shortcode for changing the focus between different spaces?

I know that you can change the focus between each app/space by

- walking through apps with  cmd + tab
- cmd + arrows to switch to neighboring spaces
- ctrl + number to change to a specific desktop (not fullscreen spaces)

What I want is a ctrl + number shortcode not only for additional desktops, but for fullscreen apps, too. Precisely a space addressing shortcode and not only a desktop addressing shortcode.

If there isn’t a solution for that, just changing the focus from one monitor to the other would be enough. At moment I always have to move the mouse to the other screen or use cmd+tab which is annoying when you have a few apps open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider using [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com)?

[Here](http://joseherran.info/blog/2014/10/11/move-cursor-and-window-through-screens/) you can see how I deal with something this. I use it to move cursor and windows between screens, but is really easy to modify per your requests.

Comment: Thank you! Keyboard Maestro works great, I will try your Macros about changing screen focus. For now I created hotkeys for the desired apps, I don't know why I didn't set them earlier with a macro tool...

Comment: The link is dead.